# How to set a 5 char (40 bit)  ASCII password for WEP on a Linksys v8 device

Tags: wireless-router, passwords, wep

I have a Linksys FW v8, and I want to use wireless password "12345" for WEP.

I cant set it up, I just can specify a 64 or 128 bit, I want 40 bit, 5 char long.

Is it possible?

Comment: Cant you just add a few characters to the password and make it `12345678`? There isn't really much difference.

Comment: What is the exact model number of your "FW"?

Comment: linksys wrt54g with FW (firmware) v8.0

Answer (score 1):

### Choose 64-bit.

Wikipedia [says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy)

> A *64-bit* WEP key is usually entered as a string of 10 hexadecimal (base 16) characters (0-9 and A-F). Each character represents four bits, 10 digits of four bits each gives **40 bits**; adding the *24-bit IV* produces the complete *64-bit* WEP key. **Most devices also allow the user to enter the key as five ASCII characters**, each of which is turned into eight bits using the character's byte value in ASCII;

---

Update:

### DD-WRT

If your router software doesn't have features that you want, you can always check if the hardware is supported by [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database) and whether that supports the features you need. Since the source is available, you can add features you want (or pay a developer to add them for you)

Updating firmware usually has the potential to render your device unusable. People updating firmware have to be prepared for that outcome.

### WEP

*Of course, we all know WEP is insecure and a 5-character key is insecure. You know that, I just want to remind anyone else reading this that WPA2 is the way to go unless you are just playing at breaking into your own router or something.*

Comment: Written in bold wont apply for my WRT54g linksys.. Any way i can go with the direct password instead of using a passphrase to be hexed to my pass?

Comment: @NicolasS: See updated answer.

Comment: @NicolasS: If you type in a passphrase of "12345" and click "generate", what Hex values do you get for Keys 1-4?

Comment: some 10 digit hex passes.. Im just doing this to imitate another access point, so some old people can have the same essid and pass in their home and office, no one is going to crack the pass there is even a faster open network... i just want WEP pasword "12345", this is becoming harder than i thought. I wont install ddwrt, unless there is no way i can go with 5 char ascii pass..

Comment: @NicolasS: The reason I asked for the Hex values is so that we can work out the relationship between the passphrase and the exact hex values. That way you may be able to work out what passphrase is needed to produce the hex equivalent of 12345. (31 32 33 34 35)

Comment: oh i will try that and come back